# How to fix the appearance of power (10^x) on axis, so it will be near or at the x axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, axis, bar

I am plotting a bar plot and the power (10^x) at x-axis located very far from the axis as shown in the figure below:

[image]

I used the following codes to plot the figure:
\pgfplotstableread{datahis.dat}\loadedtable

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1]
 \begin{axis}[ybar, 
    ybar interval = 1,
    mark = none,
    draw = none,
    xtick={ 2e6,4e6, 6e6,8e6, 10e6},
    ytick={ 2e+3,4e+3,6e+3,8e+3,10e+3, 12e+3 },
    xmax =10.199969990000000000e+06,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    grid = none, 
    ylabel = {{\small Raw Events}},
    xlabel = {{\small Time ($\mu$s)}},
    tick align=inside,
    tickpos=left,
    every axis plot post/.append style=
    {mark=none},
    legend columns=-1,
    area style,
    bar width = 0.6
    ]
    \addplot +[ybar, draw=blue,fill=black!30!white, mark = none] table[x= edges, 
    y=bins] from \loadedtable;
    \addplot[red,sharp plot,update limits=false]
    coordinates {(7.866602500000000000e+05, 200) (9.086350000000000000e+06,200)}
    node[above] at (axis cs:7.8407000000000000e+06,270) {\footnotesize{Threshold 
    rate}};
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
```

Can someone advise how to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please complete your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)].

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](//tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Please always post compilable code - it is very annoying to have to recreate your graph before being able to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would normally add the `small` option to the axis for small graphs, but you can also just move the multiplier up like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=5cm,
xmin=0, xmax=10e6,
ymin=0, ymax=12e+3,
xtick={2e6,4e6, 6e6,8e6,10e6},
ytick={2e+3,4e+3,6e+3,8e+3,10e+3,12e+3},
xmax =10e+06,
enlargelimits=0.05,
ylabel={\small Raw Events},
xlabel={\small Time ($\mu$s)},
tick align=inside,
tickpos=left,
x tick scale label style={yshift=4pt},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Empty graph with axis multiplier moved up a bit]

Comment: It works for me. Thank you